# Improve performance while Traversing List

Tags: java, performance, iteration

I was trying to write a Java program to compare previous records while traversing. It returns true if element exists previously, else false.

e.g.

- if elements are `{"Raj","Jas","Kam","Jas"}` then return `true` (since `Jas` element available previously)
- if elements are `{"Raj","Jas","Kam","Tas"}` then return `false`

I have written the below code, but its complexity is `n*n`, which is not good.  How could I write clean code to improve the performance?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class CompareList {
    private List<String> listNames;
    private List<String> listTempName = new ArrayList<>();

    public CompareList(String[] vListArray) {
        listNames = Arrays.asList(vListArray);
    }
    public CompareList(List<String> vListName) {
        listNames = vListName;
    }
    public boolean isPreviousNameExist() {
        String tempName = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listNames.size(); i++) {
            tempName = listNames.get(i);
            if (listTempName.contains(tempName)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                listTempName.add(tempName);
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] nameArray = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
        CompareList compareList = new CompareList(nameArray);
        System.out.println("==>" + compareList.isPreviousNameExist());
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**

I have updated the code and tried using a recursive way, same way how we sort using MergeSort and find its performance better for a large number of records, compared to HashSet. I believe its complexity is O(log n).

```
public class NameComparator {

    private String[] listNames;

    private String[] listTempNames;

    private boolean compareFlag = false;

    private int size;
    public boolean isNameAlreadyExist(String[] vListNames) {
        this.listNames = vListNames;
        size = vListNames.length;
        this.listTempNames = new String[size];
        checkAndSort(0, size - 1);
        return compareFlag; 
    }
    private void checkAndSort(int low, int high) {

        //Use the merge sort
        }
    }
    ..............................
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually change the performance to `O(n)` by changing one line of code here (and adding a couple of imports):

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

...

private Set<String> listTempName = new HashSet<>();
```

Although this works, we can simplify the code a little bit. Effectively, you want to see if the list of elements in the given `List` are *unique*. There's a really easy way to do this: add them all to a `Set`. If the size of the set and the size of the list are equal, then there are no duplicates. If the sizes are different, then there must be 1 or more duplicate elements. With this, we can simplify your code to:

```
public boolean isPreviousNameExist() 
{
    for(String name : listNames) {
        listTempName.add(name);
    }
    return listNames.size() != listTempName.size();
}
```

A slight improvement based on comment by @bowmore:

```
public boolean isPreviousNameExist()
{
    for(String name : listNames) {
        if(!listTempName.add(name)) {
            return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks Yuushi, Is it any other way without using hashing?

Comment: Well, you can use a `TreeSet`, which (by default) uses natural ordering to search for elements (which is `O(log n)` instead of amortized `O(1)`). Is there any real reason you want to avoid hashing?

Comment: thanks Yuushi, I only have doubt if it support large datas?

Comment: You can break early from the loop if `Set.add()`returns `false`

Comment: How large a data set are you expecting? This will handle millions of elements quite happily.

Comment: thanks Yuushi and bowmore. Just one more question. Can we do the same kind of solution with O(n) complexity without using collection?

Comment: `O(n)`, not that I can think of. There is an `O(n log n)` solution: sort the original array, and then loop through it, checking adjacent elements. This could potentially be better if memory is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your complexity is indeed O<sub>(n<sup>2</sup>)</sub> because you traverse a list bounded by n for each n elements of your list.

You can reduce this list to O<sub>(n * log(n))</sub> quite easily:

- Sort your array -> O<sub>(n * log(n))</sub>
- Compare each element with the next one `listNames.get(i).equals(listNames.get(i+1))` -> O<sub>(n)</sub>

Total is O<sub>(n * log(n))</sub>

---

#### Edit:

If you are really interested on the true/false result, there is a pretty one-liner solution :

```
return listNames.size() == new HashSet(listNames).size();
```

The `HashSet` will filter duplicate elements, hence will be smaller if there are any duplicates. It runs in O<sub>(n)</sub>, as insertion in a `HashSet` is O<sub>(1)</sub>

Comment: thanks njZk2 and sybOrg. I did just small modification in sorting approach. I sort through merge sort(recursive approach) as considering large data and while sorting i compare the element with flag. I updated the code. Please review the same and provide suggestion.